# hi there i want to record audio and video using my ubuntu computer. Im a beginner, where do I start?

Tags: sound, video

I am open to using the command line or software, but I'm very new to programming and would need a step by step guide as to how to do that. If there is simple software for recording audio and video i would be open to that as well. I'm just looking to record a video that could be posted on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/), also known as **OBS**.

Features include:

- **High performance real time video/audio capturing** and mixing. Create scenes made up of multiple sources including window captures, images, text, browser windows, webcams, capture cards and more.
- Intuitive audio mixer with per-source filters such as noise gate, noise suppression, and gain. Take full control with VST plugin support.
- Set up an unlimited number of scenes you can switch between seamlessly via custom transitions.
- Powerful and easy to use configuration options. Add new Sources, duplicate existing ones, and adjust their properties effortlessly.
- Streamlined Settings panel gives you access to a wide array of configuration options to tweak every aspect of your broadcast or recording.
- Modular 'Dock' UI allows you to rearrange the layout exactly as you like. You can even pop out each individual Dock to its own window.
- OBS supports all your favorite streaming platforms and more.

**You can find OBS and install it using the GUI software center...**

**Or you can use `apt` to install the package  `obs-studio`:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install obs-studio
```